# with another ones or with other ones?

Tags: adjectives

This is a line [from a newspaper](https://www.scmp.com/news/people-culture/trending-china/article/3198150/us4200-earrings-too-much-chinese-official-berated-luxury-accessories-press-event-triggering-official?module=perpetual_scroll_0&pgtype=article&campaign=3198150):

> Hohhot, the capital city of Inner Mongolia, has recorded 286 confirmed coronavirus cases **with another 2,371 asymptomatic ones** since last month.

Is it wrong?  I think it should be “with other 2,371 asymptomatic ones”.

Comment: https://www.scmp.com/news/people-culture/trending-china/article/3198150/us4200-earrings-too-much-chinese-official-berated-luxury-accessories-press-event-triggering-official?module=perpetual_scroll_0&pgtype=article&campaign=3198150

Comment: The sentence is correct.  Did you look up the word [**another**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not wrong.  By including the definite number in there, we require "another".  Similar examples:

- *I'll have another two of those, please.*
- *The fine weather lasted another four days.*

Comment: It strikes me that you could say "1234 cases, with 456 other cases reported this month" although it doesn't feel like as natural a phrasing.

Comment: Yes @stangdon (I agree it sounds somewhat unnatural, and I'd probably use a different word, e.g. _further_, in place of _other_ there)

Comment: I agree your sentences sound more natural but I learnt the rule like “another book”, “other books”, “the other book” and “the other books”.  From what perspective can I unite the above rule with “another four days”?

Comment: _Another book, [some] other books_ but _another two books_.